# Why is slush pool showing my worker as off?

Tags: mining-pools, guiminer, slush

I've recently started mining with slush pool, I've also tried antpool yet on both mining pools it shows that the worker is off. I am very experienced with computers and have already setup port forwarding. I realize this is a duplicate question but I feel I need a personalized answer, my hash rate is around 233.2Mhash/s. if this does not meet the minimum requirement, could someone please point me to a pool with a lower requirement. Please let me know if you need any logs or system specs. to solve this problem. (Yes I realize mining with GPU is obsolete although I lack funds to invest in a professional miner.)

Thanks in advance,

Jake